# RTCPeerConnection.addIceCandidate() - Uncaught SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified

Tags: javascript, webrtc

The `addIceCandidate()` function is giving me the error from the post title, "Uncaught SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified."

The parameter that I pass is clearly an RTCIceCandidate object. I can print out its `candidate`-attribute result, some of them look like `a=candidate:1086438664 2 udp 41754367 41.117.144.193 64564 typ relay raddr 82.146.26.23 rport 58089 generation 0` and so on.

This is the function where I pass the parameter:

```
function receiveIceCandidate(candidate)
{
    parseCandidate = new RTCIceCandidate(JSON.parse(candidate));
    //console.log("parseCandidate.cand = " + parseCandidate.candidate);
    remotePc.addIceCandidate(parseCandidate);
    //remotePc is an RTCPeerConnection
}
```

Before this function is ever called, the remotePc receives an SDP offer and sets it as its RemoteDescription, in the following function:

```
function receiveOffer(offer)
{   
    var isChrome = !!navigator.webkitGetUserMedia;
    var STUN = {
    url: isChrome
        ? 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'
        : 'stun:23.21.150.121'
    };

    var TURN = {
        url: 'turn:homeo@turn.bistri.com:80',
        credential: 'homeo'
    };

    var iceServers = 
    {
        iceServers: [STUN, TURN]
    };

    var sdpConstraints = {
    optional: [],
    mandatory: {
        OfferToReceiveAudio: true,
        OfferToReceiveVideo: true
        }
    };

    pc_config = {"iceServers": [{"url": "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"}]};

    remotePc = newPeerConnection(iceServers); // This returns a PeerConnection with suitable prefix for the browser
    remotePc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(offer.sdp ));   

    remotePc.createAnswer(function(answer) 
    { 
        console.log("creating answer.");
        remotePc.setLocalDescription(answer);
    });

    remotePc.onaddstream = function (evt) 
    { 
        console.log("on add stream..");
        var remote_video = $("#remoteVideo");
        remote_video.src = createObjectURL(evt.stream);     
    }
}
```

`onaddstream` and `createAnswer` are actually never called so far - could that be related to the problem? I don't think there's a chance to answer without ICECandidates?

Comment: Update: Actually the RemoteDescription hadn't been set, I had gotten no error about it, and the ones that I do get now are about as helpful as the one above. I doubt it but maybe this information helps someone else who's stumbling around in the lands of "no documentation, cryptic apis and things that may or may not be bugs".